# Why everything low-level is written in C?

Tags: c, low-level

Why everything low-level is written in C?

I mean kernel code, drivers, Run-time libraries, compilers, embedded systems s/w are mainly written in C/C++.

Why not use Fortran, COBOL, Pascal or even Java/C# or some other third-generation programming language that produces machine-independent code but also gives you the freedom to do low-level ,tweaks and optimizations.

My question is why developers and companies ended up using mostly C for these purposes.

Edit: Most of you here talk about performance. So, is the reason that there is no other general-purpose low-level language faster than C?

Comment: Its super fast and you have direct access to everything (not like in when running in "virtual machine")

Comment: Multics was written in PL/I almost 50 years ago. The Lisp Machine OS was written in Lisp.

Comment: Note that while you can write pretty "low level" stuff in C++, you are certainly not forced to. C++ is multi-paradigm and has many "high-level" features (lambdas to quote only one).

Comment: I would say "ubiquity, and there are so many C libraries/system-calls". It is not the only language, by any means. It's just very popular for a "bare" high-level language.

Comment: I'm 80% sure this question is a joke. Java and C# do not produce machine independent code because they don't produce any code, but bytecode which is interpreted. I'm pretty sure next Windows version will have all low level code in JS, though.

Comment: Now the question has been edited, it seems not opinion-based: it's a history question: C was created to create that kind of software

Comment: @MaPePeR Java and C# don't produce bytecode, their compilers do. In theory you could create a compiler to produce machine code from C# or Java.

Comment: Yes, Java and C# compilers (written in C?) produce bytecode, which is then interpreted by the interpreter (written in C?). I think your "In theory" needs to be all caps and bold. Well: there is gcj. I think one can reduce the question to "Why is every low-level code written in a language intended for low-level code". Also C/C++ is the only compiled language from Panayotis list, which uses "C-Style" and does not use a lot of BEGIN/ENDs. I think there is a reason most new programming languages have adopted that style.

Comment: And don't forget about the "Microsoft .Net Native" Project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few points:

- Pascal is not low level language but there are [kernels and even whole OS written in it](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Operating_Systems_written_in_FPC).
- You would not want to have a OS written in Java\C# because it will be darn slow.
- C is probably not the best language. It has many cavities, and improvements like D or C++ have been tried. The only "problem" is inertia, C is still popular because C is the most widely used programming language (weather you like it or not). There is a plethora of kernels\OS\libraries\books\course with this language. It would take decades to replace it. And it seems that despite its cavities, there is very little will to completely replace it.

Comment: Original Pascal supported p-code.

Comment: Well, I thing inertia might be the real reason...

Comment: C is (at its core) structured assembly language (PDP-11 to be exact).  As a structured assembly language, it lends itself to building robust code at the CPU instructionset level.  However, since the (defunct) PDP-11 instruction set doesn't mirror the (modern) x86 instruction set very well, the c compilers have a lot more work to do to make use of the features of current generation CPU's.

Answer (score 2):

Some would say that the type of mind capable of writing low-level stuff can only be forged by years of damage caused by using C :-)

On a more serious note, the whole purpose of C was as a systems programming language and, as such, it mostly keeps out of your way. Other languages have different purposes: COBOL is really for transactional/business stuff, C# is for applications running under MS Windows, LISP is for people who have love counting parentheses, and so on. They can be *used* for other things but I wouldn't write an operating system in COBOL.

Or an accounting package in assembler.

Or *anything* in Pascal :-)

C allows you unfettered access to the lowest levels without having to concern yourself with things like garbage collection which may adversely affect your code in ways you can't foresee.

Answer (score 2):

Java (and all JVM-based languages) and C#/F# run inside "virtual machines". That means the applications written in these languages cannot use hardware resourses directly, they are contained weithin a "sandbox". It helps portability ("runs everywhere where a VM is implemented") but can hurt performance (and does).

Answer (score 1):

Because, comparatively, C and C++ are [low level programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-level_programming_language). Some people still write in Assembler. I hope no one still writes in machine code. Anyway,

> Why not use Java, C#, COBOL, Pascal or some other third-generation programming language that produces machine-independent code but also gives you the freedom to do low-level tweaks and optimizations?

Those languages are classified as [high level languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_programming_language). They provide a level of machine abstraction that is beneficial for programming, but not useful for low level bare metal development. Also, relevant might be [Why Pascal is Not My Favorite Programming Language](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/bwk-on-pascal.html) by BWK.